# Three different roles, three different views

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement

I'm currently in a school-project and we are doing a site where there are three different types of roles.

In our user-table we have an attribute named "role". This role has a table with 3 different values, 1, 2 and 3.

1 (Admin)
2 (Adminuser)
3 (user).

What I want is: When someone is logging in, the code wants to look for what value in role this user has and then redirect this user to "admin.php" (if the value is 1), "adminuser.php" (if the value is 2) or "user.php" if the value is 3.
This is the current code, and it works so that you can login, but you get sent to the same page regardless.

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
 $query = <<<END
 SELECT email, password, userID, FROM user
 WHERE email = '{$_POST['email']}'
AND password = '{$_POST['password']}'
END;
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($res->num_rows > 0)
{
 $row = $res->fetch_object();
 $_SESSION["email"] = $row->email;
 $_SESSION["userID"] = $row->id;
header("Location:admin.php");
  }
  else
 {
 echo "Fel email eller lösenord.";
 }
}
```

Comment: Good luck with that :) If you come across any problems please feel free to return with your code - remember to include any errors you're getting.

Comment: Whats the `$_SESSION["userID"]` contain??

Comment: It contains a number right now. But it will be a sort of license number in the near future.

Comment: How to get the roles?? I mean where to get the roles of the user? Where is the user-table?

Comment: There's nothing in your code to check for the magical 1, 2 or 3 value. You'll need to store it in a column in the users table (or elsewhere). Pull the matching record from the table, then check the value of this column, doing different things depending on (a) whether or not there is a single row returned and (b) what the value of the column is. In the case of (a) you either continue the script or not, in the case of (b) you only get there if (a) was okay, so you then need to goto 1 of 3 pages.

Comment: If it is in `user` table then its a simple way to do this.

Comment: The role attribute is in the user-table as a foreign key.

Comment: so you have to retrieve it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the role is in the user table then try this with a simple array.
Below the simple code from where you can get your desire output.

```
$role = array("1"=> "Admin.php", "2"=> "Adminuser.php", "3"=> "user.php");
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  $query = <<<END
  SELECT email, password, userID, id FROM user
  WHERE email = '{$_POST['email']}'
  AND password = '{$_POST['password']}'
  END;
  $res = $mysqli->query($query);
  if ($res->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $res->fetch_object();
    $_SESSION["email"] = $row->email;
    $_SESSION["userID"] = $row->id;

    //retrieve the user role from user-table, i use userid, you may use your own field
    $query2 = <<<END
    SELECT role FROM user-table
    WHERE userid = '{$row->id}'
    END;
    $res2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
    $row2 = $res2->fetch_object();

    header("Location: ".$role[$row2->role]);
  }else{
    echo "Fel email eller lösenord.";
  }
}
```